# D3.JS lost bar chart text after adding title

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

This is the full code of my graph

```js
var dataset = [42.7, 42.7, 43.51];

var width  = 400; 
var height = 400; 
 
var svg = d3.select("body")   
   .append("svg")   
   .attr("width", width) 
   .attr("height", height);
   
var xAxisWidth = 300;

var yAxisWidth = 300;
   
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Raptors", "Opponents", "League Average"])
    .rangeRoundBands([0,xAxisWidth], 0.5);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([40, 45])
    //.domain([80,d3.max(dataset)])
    .range([0,yAxisWidth]);   
 
var padding = { top: 30 , right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30 };
    
var title = "Total Rebound";
    
svg.append("g")
    .append("text")
    .text(title)
    .attr("class", "title")
    .attr("x", width/4)
    .attr("y", padding.top);


var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)  
    .enter()   
    .append("rect") 
    .attr("fill","steelblue")  
    .attr("x", function(d,i){  
     return padding.left + + 40 + i * 85;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d){  
     return height- padding.bottom - yScale(d);
    })
    .attr("width", 50)  
    .attr("height",function(d){ 
     return yScale(d);
    });
    
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)   
    .enter()    
    .append("text")   
    .attr("fill","white")
    .attr("font-size","14px")
    .attr("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){
     return padding.left + 40 + i * 85;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d){
     return height- padding.bottom - yScale(d);
    })
    .attr("dx",xScale.rangeBand()/2)
    .attr("dy","1em")
    .text(function(d){
     return d;
    });

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");

yScale.range([yAxisWidth,0]);
    
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");
    
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","axis")
  .attr("transform","translate(" + padding.left + "," + (height - padding.bottom) +  ")")
  .call(xAxis);
   
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","axis")
  .attr("transform","translate(" + padding.left + "," + (height - padding.bottom - yAxisWidth) +  ")")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line{
 fill: none;
 stroke: black;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
 
.axis text {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In D3.js if I draw a bar chart like this
[image]

when I want to add the title above it 
after I write

```
svg.append("g")
.append("text")
.text(title)
.attr("class", "title")
.attr("x", width/4)
.attr("y", padding.top);
```

the graph become and the first number of the bar lost
[image]

how to fix this problem?

Comment: can you add your full code in a fiddle?

Comment: Added full code. Thank you

Comment: If you want to understand what happened, have a look at this example in S.O. Docs: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2135/selections/16948/the-role-of-placeholders-in-enter-selections#t=201703100514484503585

Comment: Thank you very much! It become clear to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the part of the code which adds the title to the bottom of your script will solve your problem.

Appending the title first is somehow conflicting with your bar labels. My guess would be that it is because you're appending the `title` text first and then you're doing a `svg.selectAll('text')` later on which is causing the issue.

```
var dataset = [42.7, 42.7, 43.51];

var width = 400;
var height = 400;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var xAxisWidth = 300;

var yAxisWidth = 300;

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["Raptors", "Opponents", "League Average"])
  .rangeRoundBands([0, xAxisWidth], 0.5);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([40, 45])
  //.domain([80,d3.max(dataset)])
  .range([0, yAxisWidth]);

var padding = {
  top: 30,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 30
};

var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return padding.left + +40 + i * 85;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return height - padding.bottom - yScale(d);
  })
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d);
  });

var text = svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("font-size", "14px")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return padding.left + 40 + i * 85;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return height - padding.bottom - yScale(d);
  })
  .attr("dx", xScale.rangeBand() / 2)
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom");

yScale.range([yAxisWidth, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding.left + "," + (height - padding.bottom) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding.left + "," + (height - padding.bottom - yAxisWidth) + ")")
  .call(yAxis);


var title = "Total Rebound";

svg.append("g")
  .append("text")
  .text(title)
  .attr("class", "title")
  .attr("x", width / 4)
  .attr("y", padding.top);
```

Check the jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/3hwxfdxk/

Comment: Thanks ! Learned from you

Comment: @sparta93 there is no "conflict". See the example I linked at the question's comments.